# Is there a way to transfer column metadata like policy tags from source table to target table?

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

### What I am trying to do

Given we have a source table  with this schema.yml

```
version: 2

models:
- name: source_table
  columns:
    - name: field_1
      policy_tags:
        - policy_tag_1
```

we use this source as reference in creating another table

```
select field_1
from {{ref('source_table')}}
```

Is it possible to transfer the policy tag to new columns of the table as well ? Without having to explicitly mention it in new schema.yml for the new model ?

I have checked official dbt documentation but couldnt find it https://docs.getdbt.com